# Invalid file name error in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I often encounter the following error:

> res\drawable\my-image-48.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]

My file name is "my-image-48.png" which seems to conform to the constraints listed in the error.

What am I missing?

Comment: have you tried `/` instead of backslash?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you cannot use the dash `-`, you only can use letters (from a to z), numbers (0 from 9) and underscores `_`  So you should replace "-" by underscores.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `-` .

`[a-z0-9_.]` means not you can use `-`, but that you can use letters from a to z and numbers form 0 to 9 and underscores. Therefore I recommend to substitute `-` with `_`

Answer (score 1):

The dash is not authorized in file names.